# Does production mode in Vaadin 24 require pro license?

Tags: vaadin-flow

I'm using 24.0.0.alpha4 and vaadin-core in my pom.xml. vaadin-testbench dependency is removed. Project is created at start.vaadin.com. When building in production mode a license is requested. Is this something new in v. 24, or just a glitch in an alpha-version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a glitch.

As a workaround, you can manually exclude `flow-polymer-template` that is accidentally brought in as a dependency of `vaadin-core`.

Comment: Thx, glad to hear that. Many large projects tend to use React or similar these days, but in projects where you really don't need to use React, Vaadin Flow is a huge boost, abstracting away the entire web-stack, so it is nice to know I can continue using it in projects where there is no budget for licenses (or managing a React-based technology stack). Also dying to try the native stuff in Spring Boot 3, but it doesn't play well with Vaadin Flow 23 yet (some jakarta/javax namespace clash it seems)