# Does production mode in Hills 2.0.0.beta1 (Vaadin) require a pro license?

Tags: vaadin, hilla

This is happening also for Hilla version 2.0.0.beta1.

See: [Does production mode in Vaadin 24 require pro license?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74567558/does-production-mode-in-vaadin-24-require-pro-license)

It always asks for a license and I'm using just core components. Any other work-around or is the same case as Vaadin 24.0.0?

When you compile for production mode is ask for a pro license

Answer (score 0):

It's currently a [know bug](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/15871) in 24.0.0.beta1 which is hopefully fixed in the next beta or you can downgrade to the latest alpha, where this problem isn't present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Today I tested with Hilla version 2.0.0.beta2 and the problem was solved